# mysqldump OS errno 13 - Permission denied

Tags: mysql

Выдали новый компьютер с процессором AMD
Накатил новую версию WIndows 10 сборка 19042.685
Как обычно поставил OpenServer
Базу импортировал без вопросов - все ок.
А вот дальше начались траблы
Пытаюсь экспортировать свежую базу с помощью mysqldump

команда:

mysqldump.exe next_auth --result-file=D:\woodcrafts\sqlbackups --user=root --password=root --host=127.0.0.1 --port=3306

Получаю в ответ:
Can't create/write to file 'D:\woodcrafts\sqlbackups' (OS errno 13 - Permission denied)

Нашел это:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61536742/mysqldump-with-windows10-os-errno-13-permission-denied-when-executing-sel

Дал права на папку вообще всем кого нашел - результат точно такой же.
Windows ставил сам, соответственно я - администратор.

Подскажите пожалуйста что еще можно сделать.

Comment: Yes, I'm change folder  ( another drive)- no results. 
I'm import database using phpmyadmin - ok
I'm see database using phpstorm - ok
Problem in mysqldump only

Comment: Да блин! уже языки путаю... В общем, проверяй всё, что связано с выводом в файл (SELECT .. INTO OUTFILE). Собака где-то там порылась. MySQLDump - не более чем огрызок клиента командной строки, заточенный под единственную операцию. phpmyadmin - не показатель, там экспорт выполняет PHP. А здесь пишет та учётная запись, от имени которой запускается служба MySQL-сервера... кстати, проверь, есть ли у неё права на каталог (см. эффективные права).

Comment: >> от имени которой запускается служба MySQL-сервера.
Спасибо за подсказку - сейчас попробую узнать от какой учетки эта служба запустилась

Comment: *сейчас попробую узнать от какой учетки эта служба запустилась* А чё там узнавать? См. свойства службы, вкладка "Вход". По умолчанию - сетевая служба.

Answer (score 0):

Благодаря Akina я добился нужного результата!

1. В настройках OpenServer поставил "требовать учетную запись администратора
2. Запустил OpenServer от имени администратора

Все сработало!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]